# Solve the equation $y^{\prime\prime}+\frac1xy^\prime+\frac1{x^2}y=2\sin(\ln x)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the equation $y^{\prime\prime}+\dfrac{1}{x}y^\prime+\dfrac{1}{x^2}y=2\sin(\ln x)$.

I have tried to solve it but I can't solve $y^{\prime\prime}+\dfrac{1}{x}y^\prime+\dfrac{1}{x^2}y=0$ because I can't guess one solution of this. Thank you.

Comment: Its Cauchy Euler 's equation  Try $y=x^m$ And find m

Comment: @Isham If $y=x^m$ then I have the equation $m^2+1=0$ :(

Comment: then $m=i,-i$ .....$y=c_1 \cos(\ln x)+c_2\sin( \ln x)$ for the homogeneous equation.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y(x)=u(\log(x))$ then we see that
\begin{align}
y' = \frac{1}{x}u'(\log(x)) \ \ \text{ and } \ \ y''=-\frac{1}{x^2}u'(\log(x))+\frac{1}{x^2}u''(\log(x))
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
y''+\frac{1}{x}y'+\frac{1}{x^2}y =&\ -\frac{1}{x^2}u'(\log(x))+\frac{1}{x^2}u''(\log(x))+\frac{1}{x^2}u'(\log(x))+\frac{1}{x^2}u(\log(x)) \\
=&\ \frac{1}{x^2}u''(\log(x))+\frac{1}{x^2}u(\log(x))=0.
\end{align}
Hence we have the equation $u''(\tau)+u(\tau) = 0$ which means
\begin{align}
u(\tau) = c_1\cos(\tau)+c_2\sin(\tau) \ \ \implies \ \ y(x) = u(\log(x))=c_1\cos(\log(x))+c_2\sin(\log(x)).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2y''+xy'+y=2x^2 \sin (\ln x)$$
For  Euler-Cauchy's equation, try:
 $$y=x^m \implies m^2+1=0 \implies m=i,-i$$
$$x^i=e^{i \ln x}=\cos (\ln x)+i \sin (\ln x)$$
$$x^{-i}=e^{-i \ln x}=\cos (-\ln x)+i \sin (-\ln x)$$
$$x^{-i}=\cos (\ln x)-i \sin (\ln x)$$

### $$\implies y_h=Ax^i+Bx^{-i}=c_1 \cos ( \ln x)+c_2 \sin (\ln x)$$

For the particular solution try

$$x^2y''+xy'+y=2x^2 \sin (\ln x)$$
$$y_p=Ax^2 \sin ( \ln x)+Bx^2 \cos (\ln x)$$

Answer (score 0):

To solve $y^{\prime\prime}+\dfrac{1}{x}y^\prime+\dfrac{1}{x^2}y=0$, multiply both sides by $x^2$ to get $x^2y^{\prime\prime}+xy^\prime+y=0$ and then let $x=e^t$, hence $y^{\prime}_x = \dfrac{y^{\prime}_t}{x^{\prime}_t}=y^{\prime}_te^{-t}$ and $y^{\prime\prime}_x = \dfrac{({y^{\prime}_te^{-t})}^{\prime}_t}{x^{\prime}_t}=(y^{\prime\prime}_t-y^{\prime}_t)e^{-2t}$.
Also, with this substitions right side equals $2e^{2t}\sin(t)$ (after multiplying by $x^2$), so you can easily find particular solution.

Answer (score 0):

To solve $Ly=2x^2\sin\ln x$ with $L:=x^2D^2+xD+1,\,D:=\frac{d}{dx}$, note that $Lx^n=(n^2+1)x^n$, so $\sum_\pm A_\pm x^{\pm i}$ is the CF. This can, of course, be rewritten as a linear combination of $\cos(\ln x),\,\sin(\ln x)$. Since $Ly=ix^{2-i}-ix^{2+i}$, our PI is$$\begin{align}\frac{i}{(2-i)^2+1}x^{2-i}-\frac{i}{(2+i)^2+1}x^{2+i}&=\frac{-1+i}{8}x^{2-i}+\frac{-1-i}{8}x^{2+i}\\&=\frac14x^2(\sin\ln x-\cos\ln x).\end{align}$$